# Mailchimp mc:hideable hides the wrong section within repeatable block

Tags: email, mailchimp, mcedit

I've built a custom mailchimp template and added repeatable and hideable sections so my client can edit it more easily. I have read all the documentation, my code validates, and the email itself functions great, except for one problem. Here's the gist of my layout - and ideally how I would like it to work (all extraneous code removed - but I can supply it separately if needed).

```
<table mc:repeatable>
  <tr>
    <td><img src="" alt="article image"></td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>
       <h2 mc:edit="article_title" mc:hideable>Optional Title</h2>
       <div mc:edit="article_body" mc:hideable>Optional content</div>
    </td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>
        <div mc:edit="article_button" mc:hideable><a href="" class="button">Optional Styled Button</a></div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

When I go into the campaign editor, I can hide sections successfully. UNTIL I duplicate the block. Once I have 2 blocks, and I hide the 1st block's h2, it hides the following div. If I hide the div, it hides the button. Note: within campaign editor it appears to hide things properly. Only when I preview the email can I see that it's hiding the wrong sections.

I have tried every variation I can think of:

1. Nesting tables for each piece of hideable content
2. Separating the edit and hideaable tags to parent/child elements
3. Renaming all the mc:edit attributes
4. Moving mc:repeatable to the tr or nested tables instead
5. Removing mc:hideable completely, except for the button (So they would delete copy rather than hiding the whole section.)

Item 5 above resulted in a completely different problem. When I duplicated the block and hid the button on the replicated block, it hid the button in the FIRST section. It's like the names are getting crossed somehow.

There's gotta be something I'm missing. Mailchimp's documentation seems really straightforward and I haven't been able to find anything about this specific issue.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I have exactly the same problem. It seems it is to do with `mc:hideable` inside `mc:repeatable`. Very annoying.

Comment: Has some more information about this emerged? I think I'm running into the same issues here, don't want to go the `mc:variant` way just yet!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a workaround instead of creating `mc:hideable` elements inside the `mc:repeatable` block I've created multiple variants using `mc:variant`, and each variant has different items inside it.

So in your example your varients would be:

- Block
- Block with title
- Block with content
- Block with button
- Block with title and content
- Block with title and button
- Block with title and content and button
- Block with content and button

This is not quite as neat as a solution but it does work.

See [here for `mc:variant` syntax.](http://templates.mailchimp.com/getting-started/template-language/)

Comment: This is exactly what I would do.  Sometimes I then create the variable sections that I want and save it as a separate template to save time in the future.

Comment: Past me thanks you very much and apologizes for never marking this as an answer until now :)